# Forwarding constructors calls 2 times copy constructor of base class

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

The following code forwards constructors from base to derived class.

Why 2 copy constructor calls? What happen in the background?

Compiled with g++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    A() { cout << "A" << endl; }
    A(const A&) { cout << "A(const A&)" << endl; }
    template<typename T> A(T a); // Needed to compile :-O
};

template<typename T>
struct C : public T { using T::T; };

int main()
{
    A a;
    C<A> ca(a);
    //C<A> caa(ca);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
A
A(const A&)
A(const A&)
```

Comment: Please post the actual code. What you posted doesn't compile: http://ideone.com/vfrOVF

Comment: @JimBuck Ok, I add a template constructor and it compiles ... for same reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By defining a constructor template in `A`, `C` will be given a constructor template with a similar signature. It is implicitly defined similarly to:

```
template<typename T>
struct C : public T
{
    //using T::T;

    C() = default;
    C(C const&) = default;

    template<typename U> C(U a) : T( std::forward<U>(a) ) {}
};
```

This now calls the copy-constructor of `A` twice: once for taking the argument by value. The second call results from `T( std::forward<U>(a) )` calling the copy-ctor of `A`. This was surprising to me, as you'd expect an *inherited* ctor to call the exact ctor of the base class of which it has been inherited. But that's not the case, overload resolution selects not the ctor template of `A`, but the plain copy-ctor `A(A const&)` (see below).

---

Interestingly, it doesn't care much what the constructor template in `A` does, it only needs to be declared. That's why in the OP, the definition can be missing; it can also be deleted (which might be a defect?).

The copy-ctor of `A` only has to be chosen during overload resolution of the initialization `T( std::forward<U>(a) )`. This is the case here: The argument is an rvalue of type `A`, which can bind directly to a `const A&` reference, as required by the copy-ctor of A. As the reference binding is direct and w/o derived-to-base conversion, the copy-ctor ranks as an Exact Match. The ctor template in `A` is ranked as an Exact Match as well, but as there's a template- and non-template function with the same rank in the overload set, the non-template function is preferred (the copy-ctor `A(A const&)`).

Comment: Per 12.9/8: "Each expression in the expression-list is of the form `static_cast<T&&>(p)`, where `p` is the name
of the corresponding constructor parameter and `T` is the declared type of `p`." I think that should be `T(static_cast<U&&>(a))`, so it should prefer `A`'s move constructor over copy constructor if one is present.

Comment: @Casey Yes, but that's just what `forward` does, and I thought `forward` might be more common / easier to be understood.

Comment: how can you prevent the double-call?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That depends on the context. Typically, you can write constructors with perfect forwarding, so you could use a `template<typename T> A(T&&);` in `A`, but that is too greedy and needs to be restricted by SFINAE. Another way is to define additional ctors in `C`. If you provide some context for the example, maybe we could come up with an appropriate solution.

Comment: @DyP Excellent explanation for `A(const&)` being a better match than the template constructor for an `A&&` parameter.

Comment: @Casey It's currently wrong :/ let me fix that. The argument is an rvalue because of the forwarding.

Comment: @Casey Now it's correct :D had only to fix one letter *lvalue->rvalue*. For one moment, I had doubts if it was still directly binding.

Comment: @DyP Ha - didn't even notice the typo, my "intellisense" autocorrected it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: To avoid the double call, you may use `template<typename T> A(const T&);` (cf http://ideone.com/m6CpaH)

Answer (score 6):

One call to `A::A(const A&)` is the base class constructor of `C<A>`.

The other is called to copy the pass-by-value parameter.